# How to Send Abandon Cart Email with Sendgrid / MEAN Stack

Tags: mean-stack, sendgrid, sendgrid-api-v3

I've implemented a MEAN stack application and added Sendgrid. I am looking to send emails/abandon cart emails based on the state of the user.

Example:

> If a user is going through a flow and abandons on page
>   2, send them a reminder email to complete the application;

I've also looked into sending an event with the [Events Webhook](https://sendgrid.com/docs/API_Reference/Webhooks/event.html) and also creating a [Unique Argument](https://sendgrid.com/docs/API_Reference/SMTP_API/unique_arguments.html), but I am not sure if either of those options is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to achieve this by using [Sengrid Contacts API](https://sendgrid.com/docs/API_Reference/Web_API_v3/Marketing_Campaigns/contactdb.html)

Prerequisites:

1. Create a custom field in Sendgrid [Sengrid Custom Fields for Email Marketing](https://sendgrid.com/docs/User_Guide/Marketing_Campaigns/custom_fields.html)
2. My application is using this [Sendgrid Client](https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-nodejs/tree/master/packages/client) npm package, [Sengrid V3 API](https://sendgrid.com/docs/API_Reference/api_v3.html), and `/v3/contactdb/recipients` endpoint

My custom field tracks which step the user is in during the application progress, so my custom field name is "progress_application_step"

If the user is on step 2 of the application, update their contact info with the current step

```
const client = require('@sendgrid/client');
client.setApiKey(SENDGRID_API_KEY);
const request = {
  method: 'PATCH',
  url: '/v3/contactdb/recipients'
};

request.data = 
[
 {
   "email": "emailforuser@mail.xxx",
   "progress_application_step": "2"
 }
];

client.request(request)
.then(([response, body]) => {
  console.log(response.statusCode);
  console.log(body);
})
```

This is still a work in progress, but I was able to achieve what I was looking to do with sending behavior emails. You can read more about Contacts API Recipients [here](https://sendgrid.api-docs.io/v3.0/contacts-api-recipients). If anyone has found a better solution for sending user-behavior emails, please let me know!